# Thunderbird WebExtension API (v78) : How to change the message display of threads on Thunderbird?

Tags: api, email, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-webextensions

I'm currently working on a project using the Thunderbird WebExtension API (v78) and I want to change how messages are displayed in Thunderbird when the thread view is selected.

Currently, the message view is as follows : [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWpOJ.png).

I can't click on a message to display it. I have to find each message to see his content.

What I'm looking to code is something like in Gmail : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEQPQ.png), the messages are not displayed but if I click on a message, it will be displayed entirely.

I'm trying to code this feature with the Thunderbird WebExtension (v78) which can be found here : https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/78/ but I can't find how to have access to elements in the thread view (the view in picture 1). I have access to the messageDisplay panel when a single message is displayed, but not when a tread is displayed.

So my question is : is there a way to access to the thread display panel ?

Thank you,

Léo

Comment: I think you may be able to get info on the messages with [`mailTabs.getSelectedMessages()`](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mailTabs.html) (I didn't check), but I don't think that would allow you to change the appearance of how the thread is displayed. I don't believe the API currently provides a way to access the thread view, you might have to fall back to [experiments](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to/experiments.html) and implementing all of it yourself, or to open a feature request :/.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! Indeed, the current API doesn't allow me to change the appearance ! I will use experiments and implement it all by myself ! I'm currently struggling to understand how to do it, if you (or anybody else) have any advice, I'll take it with pleasure :)

Comment: Sorry, I managed to find a way to avoid “experiments” for my own add-ons, so I won't be able to help you on that path. Have a look at the available examples on GitHub, also have a look at other extensions using experiments maybe. [This one](https://addons.thunderbird.net/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/) may attempt to change the look of the threaded view? (I've not used it myself). Note also that [other channels](https://www.thunderbird.net/get-involved/#communication) may be more active than SO for getting help on this topic.

Comment: I'm currently looking at the extension you linked, it's quite similar to what I want to do ! The code is quite hard to understand I'll have to manage with it ! Anyway, thank you for your help !

Comment: You're welcome, happy I could help :).